# Swift: typecast output array in Collection where Iterator.Element == Foo

Tags: arrays, swift, casting

I have the following function, it iterates over an array of `Foo`, and creates a new array using the items in the original array, but with different colors:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Foo {
    public func color(colors: [NSColor]) -> [Foo] {
        var result: [Foo] = []

        for item in self {
            for color in colors {
                let newItem = Foo(name: item.name, color: color)
                result.append(newItem)
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

This works, but if I use it on a subclass `Bar` of `Foo`, it still returns `[Foo]`, not `[Bar]`.

I could do something like this:

```
let colors: [NSColor] = // set colors
let colorArray = array.color(colors).map{ Bar($0.name, $.color)
```

But then I need to remember to do that every time I call it for a subclass of `Foo`.

So how can I adjust the function to make it work on subclasses of `Foo` as well?

**EDIT**

Based on the comment below, I tried a generic function:

```
public func color<T>(colors: [NSColor]) -> [T] {
    var result: [T] = []

    for item in self {
        for color in colors {
            let newItem = T(name: item.name, color: color)
             result.append(newItem)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

That gives me the error:

> Non-nominal type 'T' does not support explicit initialization

So I searched for that, and found I need to use `init`:

```
let newItem = T.init(name: item.name, color: color)
```

Now I get this error:

> Type 'T' has no member 'init'

`Foo` and `Bar` have an init, but that doesn't help here. Am I on the right track?

**EDIT 2**:

Martin's answer below made me realize an error in my code: `where Iterator.Element == Foo` should have been `where Iterator.Element: Foo`

Comment: You are describing a generic.

Comment: See my edit above on a generic attempt.

Comment: Your T introduces an extra type. Iterator.Element is already a generic placeholder.

Comment: Does this code warrant an extension? Looks like a simple flatMap and map to me. `foos.flatMap { item in colors.map { Element(name: item.name, color: $0) } }`

Comment: Yes, I think that is what is suggested in the accepted answer. But it should be an extension of Collection, correct? How else could I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the “same-type constraint”  by a “subclass constraint” and use the collections `Element` type instead of `Foo` in the implementation:

```
extension Collection where Element: Foo {
    func color(colors: [NSColor]) -> [Element] {
        var result: [Element] = []
        for item in self {
            for color in colors {
                let newItem = Element(name: item.name, color: color)
                result.append(newItem)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Note that this requires `Foo` (and its subclasses) to have a “required init” method:

```
required init(name: String, color: NSColor)
```

Another option is to define a protocol

```
protocol P {
    var name: String { get }
    init(name: String, color: NSColor)
}
```

to which `Foo` (and its subclasses) conform, and use the constraint

```
extension Collection where Element: P
```

for the extension method.

In any case, a more concise implementation would be

```
extension Collection where Element: Foo {
    func color(colors: [NSColor]) -> [Element] {
        return self.flatMap { item in
            colors.map { Element(name: item.name, color: $0) }
        }
    }
}
```

*Re your edit:* As a free generic method (instead of an extension method) it would be something like

```
func color<T: P>(items: [T], with colors: [NSColor]) -> [T] {
    return items.flatMap { item in
        colors.map { T(name: item.name, color: $0) }
    }
}
```

using the protocol defined above. The compiler needs to know that an instance of `T` can be created from an item name and a color.

Comment: Your answer pointed me to the error in my code (I think). Where I wrote `where Iterator.Element == Foo`, it should have been `where Iterator.Element: Foo` With that replacement, my code above works. I do really like you more concise solution with `flatMap`.

Comment: @Koen: That is one part of the solution. But you also have to change the return type from [Foo] to [Element] if you want that calling the method on an array of Bar returns [Bar] and not [Foo].

Comment: And the `required init` method.